# Django view receives GET Request from form that should be sending POST

Tags: django, forms, post, get

I have a view that is supposed to handle the submission of a form. The HTML form in the template is supposed to be sending a post however the view only ever receives a GET request.

View:

```
def eventSell(request, id):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk = id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print request.user 
        if request.method == ['POST']:
            print 'post'
            form = ListingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print 'form is valid'
                user = request.user
                price = request.POST['price']
                t = Object(event = event, price = price, seller = user, date_listed = timezone.now())
                t.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index'))
        else:
            print 'get'
            form = ListingForm()
        return render_to_response('app/list.html', {'form' : form, 'event' : event}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('allauth.accounts.views.login'))
```

Template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm really stumped here so any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably sending a `POST` however, you are not listening correctly.

```
if request.method == ['POST']:
```

should be

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Or just

```
if request.POST:
```

One more thing.

You can use the [`@login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) instead of manually checking for authenticated users.

Comment: Checking the method is preferable over checking the boolean value of `request.POST` - the latter is a subclass of the built in dictionary class and will evaluate as False for a POST request that provides no data.